# Single page app viewport mobile using Foundation

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation for a responsive website and have a problem with SOME mobile devices not properly scaling the viewport ONLY when you load another page via our ng-include. This loads new content into the page and the width of the page then breaks and requires horizontal scrolling.

This doesn't happen in certain devices such as Galaxy Note 3/4, but does happen in devices with identical resolutions, such as iPhone 6 Plus. I do have a viewport attribute and scaling set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi;">
```

Any help figuring out why this doesn't scale properly when I load new dynamic content for this single page application is greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if it's related (just thought of it), but we also use document equalizer reflow often:

```
$(document).foundation('equalizer','reflow');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a min and max scale. Although I didn't test it, I imagine I just needed to add a max scale, as the content was flowing off the screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```